# Video or GIF dynamic island - activitykit - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, dynamic-island

I started putting my hands-on the dynamic island and the activitykit and I already found out some limitations.

I would love to play a GIF or a video (MP4) into the dynamic island when leaving the app. Like those nice animations that Apple made when there is some song or something playing.

However I found out that... I receive a "forbidden" yellow and red symbol when I try to add a video or GIF (Array of images) into the dynamic island it self.

Does anybody of you knows if and how is it possible to have an animated image into the dynamic island?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the way to show animation ?

Comment: @Julius Nope! I'm thinking that Apple is just restricting those kind of features to devs. Please up vote my question so it can maybe get bigger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a chat with an Apple engineer and he told me that animations are private API's so this means IT'S NOT POSSIBLE for us to implement such a feature.

If we want this, we should open a ticket as feature request in the Feedback section of the Apple Developer website.

Comment: There is a way to expose private APIs I believe with Objective-C bridging header. There are apps already that have animation in Live Activities. They are doing it somehow. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Anyone figured out a way to do it?

Comment: Any update on this, I am facing the same issue

Comment: @amisolani still animations are not available in Dynamic Island nor widgets.

Comment: Then how does Spotify app manage to show a animated view in dynamic island

Comment: Spotify does not have animated view in dynamic island. What you see is native player from Apple. @amisolani